# Fractional differentiation. Questions about degrees of freedom and regularity of involved functions.

Tags: matrices, soft-question, fractional-calculus

I have from and to read about different definitions of fractional derivatives. That is functionals $${\bf D}^{\frac 1 k}$$ that take (often an integer) $k$ so that: $${\left({\bf D}^{\frac 1 k}\right)}^k = {\bf D}$$

So for example doing a one-third derivative three times should give us the same thing as an ordinary differential operator would ( for all functions in some set of differentiable functions ).

Consider a basis of $c_1 \sin(nx) + c_2 \cos(nx)$ with coefficients in a:

$$Dv = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-n\\n&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}c_1\\c_2\end{array}\right) = n\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}c_1\\c_2\end{array}\right)$$

We can now define as a solution to the equation $({D^\frac 1 k})^{k} = D$

What criteria can we make to make such an operation *sensible*? We could fill out with arbitrary functions which still fulfill the equation and just stuff them in between. For example a double size space:

$$D^{1/3}v = \sqrt[3]{n}\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-i\\1&0&0&0\\0&i&0&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\c_1\\0\\c_2\end{array}\right) \Leftrightarrow \left(D^{1/3}\right)^3v = n\left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&0&-i&0\\0&0&0&-1\\i&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\end{array}\right]$$

We see that for exponent 3 column 2 and 4 map on each other with $-n,n$ respectively like they should if they were the basis functions from before. But other than that, what stops us from filling out with arbitrary functions? We know they must be $in$ and $-in$ in terms of each other when doing derivative, is that enough of a constraint to enforce them to be any particular functions or do we have freedom in choosing them?